# How to get average occurrences of string in list

Tags: c#, list, average

I am trying to get an average of occurrences of a string in a list.
Basically I am trying to get the most common occurring string in a list of about 4 options.
So for instance in this example

```
List<string> lMyList = new List<string>();
lMyList.Add("One");
lMyList.Add("One");
lMyList.Add("Two");
lMyList.Add("Two");
lMyList.Add("Two");
lMyList.Add("Three");
lMyList.Add("Three");
```

I want to get "Two" returned to me...

Any ideas?

Comment: @SLaks - Maybe 1+1+2+2+2+3+3 = 14. 14/7 = 2 = two.

Comment: @SLaks - Nah, the question statement is mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
string most = lMyList.GroupBy(x => x)
        .Select(g => new {Value = g.Key, Count = g.Count()})
        .OrderByDescending(x=>x.Count).First();
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use LINQ:

```
list.GroupBy(s => s).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count()).First()
```

Comment: I definitely need to do some reading up on LINQ, I get the impression that it will make a lot of data management a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

for finding average do:

```
list.GroupBy(x => x).Average(x=>x.Count())
```

for finding max do:

```
var max = groups.OrderbyDescending(x=>x.Count()).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried this and it gave me a numeric return, basically what I was trying to do is see how often an answer is found and choose the one that is most common. Thanks for the code though I think this may take care of another issue I foresee coming up!

Comment: @Jesse Knott my first answer is for average and second one is for mood.